# Calcular tiempo entre campos de fecha y hora

Tags: mysql

Buen día a todos, por favor si pueden ayudarme, requiero lo siguiente:

-Tengo 4 campos:
 hora_inicio, hora_fin (time)
 fecha_inicio, fecha_fin (date)

Existe una tabla que contiene estos registros. Se requiere calcular el tiempo entre el primer y ultimo registro. Luego hallar el promedio de estos registros en un mes.

Hice este query, pero se requiere calcular el tiempo entre horas y fechas.

```
select o.codigo as incidente, op.hora_inicio, op.hora_fin,  
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE , op.hora_inicio, op.hora_fin ) AS Tiempo, 
op.fecha_inicio, op.fecha_fin, o.fecha, i.valor as codigo_incidente
from operacion o
inner join incidente i
on i.codigo=o.incidente_codigo
inner join operacion_detalle op
on op.codigo_operacion=o.codigo
where o.codigo='1042'
order by op.hora_inicio ASC;
```

Comment: ¿Cual es el problema/error exactamente?

Comment: No sé si sabes que los campos de tipo `DATETIME`, **como su nombre lo indica**, sirven para guardar tanto la fecha como la hora (`time`) **en un solo campo**. O sea, primeramente, si quieres optimizar ¿por qué no usas dos columnas en vez de 4? De ese modo, el campo `fecha_inicio` te guardará tanto la fecha como la hora en que se inició, y lo mismo el campo `fecha_fin`... Con respecto a la pregunta, no se entiende del todo lo que quieres hacer, creo que haría falta que te expliques un poco mejor, poniendo ejemplos del resultado esperado.

Comment: Hola Alfredo,  lo que deseo es calcular el tiempo entre el primer y ultimo registro, que considere los campos hora y fecha. Asimismo el promedio de ese calculo en un rango de fechas.

Comment: Agradezco tu observación, lo realizare mas adelante, por ahora requiero encontrar la solución para esa consulta. Agradezco tu repuesta.